# How to use Totole granulated chicken flavor soup base mix?

Tags: chinese-cuisine, bouillon

I have a can of Totole granulated chicken flavor soup base mix, but I cannot read what I presume are the directions on the back. I want to try making a Chinese-American restaurant style egg drop soup with it, but don't know what ratio to water or stock to use. Can anyone tell me how to use this?

I considered asking this on the Chinese Language Stack Exchange, but they don't allow translation requests. I also tried a translation app but didn't have much success.

[image: Back of Totole can]

Comment: I  can't answer this directly, I don't speak Chinese. If you don't get an answer, most soup mixes and stock powders are 2-3 tsp per 500ml of water, so you could  use that as a baseline. It will dissolve in seconds so you could just keep adding spoons until you get the right flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it’s up to you to decide. For clear soup, it’s about 10g per liter. The shelf life is 20 months.
For Chinese food, don’t pay too much attention to the specific dosage, you can add it little by little until you are satisfied.